# How does data deletion count on AWS RDS pricing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to estimate the cost of a RDS instance where I need to load and delete a lot of data continuously.

As I see in the AWS page for RDS pricing ([link](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mariadb/pricing/)) the `Data transfer` section is divided into `In` and `Out`. **I understand that inserts count as `In` and selects count as `Out`, but how do deletions count? Is there any documentation about the topic?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data transfer refers to data actually transferred into and out of the database instance from client connections.  Traffic between the database instance and its backing store (disk) isn't billed, so actions like `DELETE` don't incur any charges.  Queries that read and write data but don't acually return anything, like `INSERT ... SELECT` (which reads from a table and writes to another table, not returning rows to the caller) would also not be billed as data transfer.

Comment: So, if I understand properly, only client connections that retrieve and insert data are count? Moving data inside the same RDS instance and deleting data do not count for the final pricing? Thanks for your answer.